# « Un voyage se passe de motifs » ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Je ne comprends pas la relation et le sens de cette phrase que je souligne dans l'extrait qui suit d'un livre de Nicolas Bouvier :

> Quelque chose en vous grandit et détache les amarres, jusqu'au jour où, pas trop sûr de soi, on s'en va pour de bon. **Un voyage se passe de motifs.** Il ne tarde pas à prouver qu'il se suffit à lui-même. On croit qu'on va faire un voyage, mais bientôt c'est le voyage qui vous fait, ou vous défait.
>
> *L'Usage du monde* (1963), [Nicolas Bouvier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bouvier), éd. Payot, 2001, p. 12.

Comment: @HydrangéacéeslesHydrangelles Thanks for responding and editing question . I know the meaning of each word completely but I can't grasp the meaning of whole sentence .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Motifs peut signifier raisons (motivation), ou décorations/dessins/formes.

Là ça veut dire qu'on n'a pas besoin d'avoir de raison spécifique pour voyager, le voyage en lui-même se suffit à lui-même, est une raison en soi.

Comment: +1. On peut aussi parler du verbe `se passer`. Ici `se passer de` signifie qu'on peut ne pas faire/avoir besoin/utiliser quelque chose  : "ça se passe de commentaires", "Je peux me passer de toi pour terminer", etc.